# How to extract the text of the firstselectedoption from a dropdown using Selenium Webdriver through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, webdriver

After selecting an option from drop-down. I am trying to get that option displayed in the console. below is my code. But I get

```
"//[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (d5a01776981da5dacfeb89dbbc2e6b52)] -> xpath: //*[@name='airline']]].// -> tag name: option]"
```

The tag name is option for dropdown options. I have tried all solutions of selectByXXXX. but nothing seems to work. what would be the right code ?

```
//airline preference
{
    Select airline = new Select (driver.find Element(By.name("airline"))); //selecting tag
    Thread.sleep(2000); //sleeptime`
    airline.selectByVisibleText("Pangea Air"); //selecting option
    Thread.sleep(2000); //sleep time
    Select airlin = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='airline']"))); //omg
    WebElement s = airlin.getFirstSelectedOption();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly. Format your question for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### getFirstSelectedOption

[`getFirstSelectedOption()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getFirstSelectedOption--) returns the first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select). `NoSuchElementException` is thrown if no option is selected.

---

Seems you were pretty close. Once you select an option through `selectByVisibleText()` next you can invoke `getFirstSelectedOption()` to choose the option element selected and finally using `getText()` you can extract the option text as per the solution below:

- Code Block:

  ```
  Select airline = new Select (driver.find Element(By.name("airline"))); //selecting tag
  airline.selectByVisibleText("Pangea Air"); //selecting option
  WebElement s = airline.getFirstSelectedOption();
  System.out.println(s.getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Pangea Air
  ```