# How to store the value in a variable which is selected from a dropdown in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select

For example, below is the java code for Selenium automation testing and I have selected the value 9 from a static dropdown. So how do I store the value 9 in a variable?

```
WebElement staticdd1= driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$mainContent$ddl_Adult"));//name of adult dropdown
Select dd1=new Select(staticdd1);
dd1.selectByValue("9");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath with attribute method like this-

```
Xpath=//input[@value='9']
```

And then get the text from the element.
You can check the examples here-
https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

### getFirstSelectedOption()

[`getFirstSelectedOption()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getFirstSelectedOption()) returns the first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select).

So once you select the option through `selectByValue()` you can store the value as follows:

```
WebElement staticdd1= driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$mainContent$ddl_Adult"));//name of adult dropdown
Select dd1=new Select(staticdd1);
dd1.selectByValue("9");
WebElement element = dd1.getFirstSelectedOption();
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract the text of the firstselectedoption from a dropdown using Selenium Webdriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794277/how-to-extract-the-text-of-the-firstselectedoption-from-a-dropdown-using-seleniu/59795099#59795099)
- [How to print the text of the selected option choosen through 'selectByVisibleText' method in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903657/how-to-print-the-text-of-the-selected-option-choosen-through-selectbyvisibletex/50903768#50903768)